# How do I compile in debug mode? (eclipse, java, maven, javafx-maven-plugin)

Tags: debugging, javafx-2, maven-plugin, m2eclipse

I want to debug my application made in javafx and maven.
I know that mavenDebug exists but I could not make it work with eclipse, I tried several alternatives to try to debug but not succeed.
The only one that works for me to debug via "java application"

Thanks for any reply.